# How can I run my mongodb and next js project?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, database-connection

I'm trying to create a database using MongoDB and my project is next.js project. But, I'm unable to do it. The commands for running both is npm run dev but it's only running my frontend on port 3000 and not creating a database in MongoDB compass. Is there a way of doing it correctly?

I tried to run my Next.js project with MongoDB and wanted to create a database but, it didn't work instead it is only running my frontend on port 3000.